# Acumatica - Grid selector automatic refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

I've got a FormDetail page where one parameter is a selector on a form and another one is also selector on grid. When I press the grid selector it should select the objects that verify the condition, so the grid selector depends on the form selector. The selector works perfectly but there is a problem. When I select a value on a form, the grid selector doesn't refresh until I refresh it manually with a default refresh button. Is there any chance to make it work automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the `AutoRefresh` property in the page for the selector field set to `true`.

Example:

```
<px:PXSelector ID="edAField" runat="server" DataField="AField" AutoRefresh="True" />
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but SyncPosition = "True" is needed for the grid.

Comment: Yes. I believe i always just set that property in the grid as most cases its needed unless its a simple inquiry screen.